# Need help regarding array formulas implementation in apache poi api

Tags: java, apache-poi, excel-formula

I got allocated updation of existing project. Previous developer used jcom api to export data to excel sheets. But jcom api don't work with 64 bit systems. I decided to change code and using apache poi api. I managed to done many methods. My problem is array formulas. I Need to implement array formulas using apache poi. Those formulas are posted below, any help will be more appreciable. Thanks in advance guys.

Formulas:

```java
String  formula1 = "SUM(R[-2]C/1.200)";//net income  calculation from gross income
String  formula2 = "SUM(R[-1]C-R[1]C)";
String  formula3 = "SUM(R[-" + Integer.toString(listTypeTotals.size()+1) + "]C:R[-2]C)";
```

I tried to set that cell as formulatype and passing formula as string.

```java
setCellFormulaStyle(sheet, 4, i+2, formula2);

 public static void setCellFormulaStyle(HSSFSheet sheet,int row, int column,String value)
  {
    HSSFRow temprow = null;
    temprow =getRow_CreateRow(sheet, row);
    temprow.createCell(column).setCellFormula(value);
  }

public static HSSFRow getRow_CreateRow(HSSFSheet sheet,int row)
{
  HSSFRow excelrow=null;
  excelrow = sheet.getRow(row);
  if(excelrow==null)
  {
    excelrow =sheet.createRow(row);
    return excelrow;
  }else
  return excelrow;
}
```

I am getting following exception

```
org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Specified named range 'R' does not exist in the current workbook.
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseNonRange(FormulaParser.java:569)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeable(FormulaParser.java:517)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeExpression(FormulaParser.java:268)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseSimpleFactor(FormulaParser.java:1119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.percentFactor(FormulaParser.java:1079)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.powerFactor(FormulaParser.java:1066)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Term(FormulaParser.java:1426)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.additiveExpression(FormulaParser.java:1526)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.concatExpression(FormulaParser.java:1510)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.comparisonExpression(FormulaParser.java:1467)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Arguments(FormulaParser.java:1051)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.function(FormulaParser.java:936)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseNonRange(FormulaParser.java:558)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeable(FormulaParser.java:429)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeExpression(FormulaParser.java:268)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseSimpleFactor(FormulaParser.java:1119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.percentFactor(FormulaParser.java:1079)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.powerFactor(FormulaParser.java:1066)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Term(FormulaParser.java:1426)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.additiveExpression(FormulaParser.java:1526)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.concatExpression(FormulaParser.java:1510)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.comparisonExpression(FormulaParser.java:1467)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.unionExpression(FormulaParser.java:1447)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:1568)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:176)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.HSSFFormulaParser.parse(HSSFFormulaParser.java:72)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.setCellFormula(HSSFCell.java:594)`
```

Comment: Can you not re-write the formula to exclude the array references?

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks for ur reply .i have chance to rewrite the formula but what i got dynamic column numbers and rows numbers. i am trying to but no idea how to do it  using A1,B2,C3 format. formula1 will be using to calculated Net Income depends on gross income. and second formula will be using to get vat paid amount from groos income minus net income.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you have use the formula yet. However if your problem is regarding the dynamic cell reference based on rows and Columns, perhaps I can help you.

For any cell, say "B5", at runtime,

```
cell.getReference();
```

will give you cell reference (like in example... it will return you "B5"

```
cell.getReference().toString().charAt(0);
```

will give you the Column Reference (will give you "B" if the current cell is B5). Now

```
cell.getRowIndex();
```

OR

```
 cell.getReference().toString().charAt(1);
```

will give you Row Index. I have used that multiple times to update/create the Named ranges and formula on my workbook.

**Small Changes to include handling address like `AZ89`**

For the cases of AZ99 we can use  for this we can use small hacks like:

```
String str = cell.getReference();
    for(index = 0;index<str.length();index++){
        if((int)str.charAt(index)<65){
            break;
        }
    }
    String Col = str.substring(0, index);
    String Row = str.substring(index+1, str.length());
```

Comment: If you use indexing like that it will break on addresses such as `AA1`

Comment: Thanks farmerjoe... to point out some corner cases. I have updated a small hack for the same cases.

Comment: nice!  I do a lot of work with `POI` and wrote a few similar methods.   have made a library that handles a lot of operational tools that `POI` does not cover as it is mainly an `I/O` library, such as copying cells, rows, sheets, explicit handling of row/col formula shifts, searching, its a work in progress but take a look, it may be of interest to you [github page](https://github.com/joeyuan19/POIExtension/tree/master/POIExtension/src/excelUtils)