# Auto update an Excel formula

Tags: java, excel, cell, formula

I'm starting to build an app (in Java) and I am having some problems.Trying to export some information into an Excel template. I have no problem with that, but the template has some Excel formulas. When I open the template all the information is there, but in order to see the results of the formulas I have to ***copy/paste*** all the values given by the app.

I've found a sentence to update all the formulas:

```
workbookInfDef.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();
```

but it doesn't work. An error stop happens with it and the app collapses.

Comment: GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/RA] threw exception [org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Specified named range 'Tabla1' does not exist in the current workbook.] with root cause
org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Specified named range 'Tabla1' does not exist in the current workbook.

Comment: I don't know where it takes form the range 'Tabla1'... I have nothing on the template refering to that...

Comment: Take a look at this post, it may assist you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422881/need-help-regarding-array-formulas-implementation-in-apache-poi-api

Comment: Thank u!! I've seen that the sentence I was using didn't work because I was using a dinamic table. It works with a normal table.